# SNMP OID with non-unique node names

Tags: snmp, mib

I am writing an extension to my companies existing SNMP MIB.  I have a whole list of objects, with the same properties on each.  I want to be able to get and set these through SNMP.

So for example, consider my object has `name`, `desc`, `arg0`, `arg1`. What I want is to be able to refer to these as:

```
fullpath.objects.ObjectA.name
fullpath.objects.ObjectA.desc
fullpath.objects.ObjectA.arg0
fullpath.objects.ObjectB.name
fullpath.objects.ObjectB.desc
fullpath.objects.ObjectB.arg0
```

However the leaf nodes appear to have to have unique names, so I am unable to define this.

I can use a SNMP table to produce:

```
fullpath.objects.table.name.1
fullpath.objects.table.desc.1
fullpath.objects.table.arg0.1
fullpath.objects.table.name.2
fullpath.objects.table.desc.2
fullpath.objects.table.arg0.2
```

But there is nowhere to look up that `2` means `ObjectB`.  This leaves it open to user error looking up the wrong value and setting the wrong thing.

At the moment the best solution I can see is:

```
fullpath.objects.ObjectAName
fullpath.objects.ObjectADesc
fullpath.objects.ObjectAArg0
fullpath.objects.ObjectBName
fullpath.objects.ObjectBDesc
fullpath.objects.ObjectBArg0
```

which involves defining `name` for every object (there are 20 or so of them).  The set of objects is fixed, so this is ok...just not very tidy.

1. Is there some way to define names for index in the table?
2. Is there some way of defining a container type?
3. Is there some way of allowing leaf nodes to be non-unique?

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

1. You should definitely use SNMP tables to accomplish what is required. This is the only way.
2. MIB Object names **must be unique** within entire MIB file.
3. You can easily use object of `OCTET STRING` type as Table index. So each byte/symbol/char of `OCTET STRING` value will be translated to corresponding **numeric ASCII code** in `OID`.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just using a naming convention and adding each of the settings directly into the MIB.

Not really the answer I wanted, but it means that all of the settings show up in the MIB, and that reduces the chance of users setting the wrong setting.