# Must object names/descriptors be unique within an SNMP MIB module?

Tags: snmp, mib

I have a vendor-provided MIB file where the same object name/descriptor is defined in two different tables in the same MIB. Unfortunately, I think the MIB is proprietary and can't post it here in its entirety. So I've created a similar sample Foobar.mib file that I've included at the end of this post.

My question is: Is there any way such a MIB is legal or could be considered valid?

Net::SNMP can print the tree of it and it looks like this:

```
+--foobar(12345678)
   |
   +--foo(1)
   |  |
   |  +--fooTable(1)
   |     |
   |     +--fooEntry(1)
   |        |  Index: fooIndex
   |        |
   |        +-- -R-- INTEGER   fooIndex(1)
   |        +-- -R-- String    commonName(2)
   |
   +--bar(2)
      |
      +--barTable(1)
         |
         +--barEntry(1)
            |  Index: barIndex
            |
            +-- -R-- INTEGER   barIndex(1)
            +-- -R-- String    commonName(2)
```

Note now `commonName` is defined under both `fooTable` and `barTable` *in the
very same MIB* (see below in my sample `Foobar.mib`).

This confuses Net::SNMP, since `FooBarMib::commonName` can now mean two different OIDs.

It would be grand to include a link to an RFC in a bug report for the vendor.

I've found that [RFC 1155 - Structure and identification of management information for TCP/IP-based internets](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1155#section-4.1) says:

> Each OBJECT DESCRIPTOR corresponding to an object type in the
> internet-standard MIB shall be a unique, but mnemonic, printable
> string.  This promotes a common language for humans to use when
> discussing the MIB and also facilitates simple table mappings for
> user interfaces.

Does this only apply to "internet-standard MIB"s and hence not to vendor MIBs?

I've also found [RFC 2578 - Structure of Management Information Version 2 (SMIv2)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2578#section-3.1) that says:

> For all descriptors appearing in an information module, the descriptor shall be unique and mnemonic, and shall not exceed 64 characters in length.

But does a MIB for an SNMP v1 agent also have to adhere to RFC 2578? The SNMP agent
implementing the MIB only supports SNMP v1 for whatever reason. And the RFC
2578 has `SMIv2` in the title, where the `2` worries me a little. However the MIB itself does import from `SMIv2` FWIW.

I've found two internet references that say that object names / descriptors must be unique within a MIB, but without a source reference:

[Andrew Komiagin in "SNMP OID with non-unique node names"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34200990/345716) here on SO says:

> MIB Object names *must be unique* within entire MIB file.

and [Dave Shield on the Net::SNMP mailing list](https://sourceforge.net/p/net-snmp/mailman/message/18406612/) says:

> Within a given MIB module, *all* object names must be unique.
> Both the objects defined within that MIB, and objects explicitly
> IMPORTed. You can't have two objects with the same name,
> both referenced in the same MIB.

I'd love to get a standards / RFC reference for either of those two equivalent statements.

### Sample Foobar.mib

This defines `commonName` as both `::={ fooEntry 2 }` and further down as `::={ barEntry 2 }` also:

```
-- I've changed the MIB module name.
FooBarMib DEFINITIONS ::= BEGIN

IMPORTS sysName, sysLocation FROM SNMPv2-MIB;
IMPORTS enterprises, OBJECT-TYPE FROM SNMPv2-SMI;

-- I've provided a fake name and enterprise ID here

foobar OBJECT IDENTIFIER::= {enterprises 12345678}

foo OBJECT IDENTIFIER::={ foobar 1 }

fooTable OBJECT-TYPE
        SYNTAX SEQUENCE OF FooEntry
        MAX-ACCESS not-accessible
        STATUS current
::={ foo 1 }

fooEntry OBJECT-TYPE
        SYNTAX FooEntry
        MAX-ACCESS not-accessible
        STATUS current
        INDEX { fooIndex }
::={ fooTable 1 }

FooEntry ::= SEQUENCE{
        fooIndex INTEGER,
        commonName OCTET STRING,
        -- other leaves omitted
}

fooIndex OBJECT-TYPE
        SYNTAX INTEGER
        MAX-ACCESS read-only
        STATUS current
::={ fooEntry 1 }

commonName OBJECT-TYPE
        SYNTAX OCTET STRING
        MAX-ACCESS read-only
        STATUS current
        DESCRIPTION
        "Label for the commonEntry"
::={ fooEntry 2 }

bar OBJECT IDENTIFIER::={ foobar 2 }

barTable OBJECT-TYPE
        SYNTAX SEQUENCE OF BarEntry
        MAX-ACCESS not-accessible
        STATUS current
::={ bar 1 }

barEntry OBJECT-TYPE
        SYNTAX BarEntry
        MAX-ACCESS not-accessible
        STATUS current
        INDEX { barIndex }
::={ barTable 1 }

BarEntry ::= SEQUENCE{
        barIndex INTEGER,
        commonName OCTET STRING,
        -- other leaves omitted
}

barIndex OBJECT-TYPE
        SYNTAX INTEGER
        MAX-ACCESS read-only
        STATUS current
::={ barEntry 1 }

commonName OBJECT-TYPE
        SYNTAX OCTET STRING
        MAX-ACCESS read-only
        STATUS current
        DESCRIPTION
        "Label for the commonEntry"
::={ barEntry 2 }

END
```

Comment: That sounds like a broken MIB document. Imagining that you need to refer to `commonName` object in another MIB document, then how can the MIB parser/compiler knows which `commonName` from this file should be used? To avoid that kind of ambiguity, the RFC documents have forbidden such, and I believe most parsers/compilers should also give you errors. However, notice that many vendors ship broken MIB documents to their customers (even Cisco). The main reason is that people rarely read every MIB documents. You might contact the vendor for resolution.

Comment: Hi @LexLi, I hear you. I also _think_ it is broken. But do you have any specific RFC references that support "that sounds like a broken MIB document" and "RFC documents have forbidden such"?

Comment: Unfortunately, enterprises can do whatever they want. If they want to play nice, they are advised to adhere to the rules. Details at https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2578#section-3

Comment: The best way to prove it is a demo. Perform a get on the name that is used twice, that should easily illustrate that you cannot access both values with a unique key.

Comment: @vomi: Sure `snmpget ... FooBarMib::commonName` doesn't work, but `snmpget ... .1.3.$whatever` _does_. Is a working `snmpget FooBarMib::commonName` an actual RFC-based requirement? (Which RFC?) The vendor could rightfully claim that both `snmpbulkget ... FooBarMib::fooTable` and `snmpbulkget ... FooBarMib::barTable` works just fine so use that instead :-)

Comment: @GambitSupport: If you'd care to change your comment into an answer, I'd accept it. RFC 2578's 'It is strongly recommended that "enterprise-specific" information modules also adhere to these restrictions.' I guess I'm not going to get stronger wording than that. I'm just surprised this isn't unambiguous in the RFC whether uniqueness is a requirement or not for enterprise MIBs.

Comment: It would be impossible to guarantee uniqueness. Added the answer.

Comment: Sure, global uniqueness, as in "`commonName` is unique across all MIB files in the universe" is not possible. But uniqueness within a single MIB file is definitely doable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, enterprises can do whatever they want. If they want to play nice, they are advised to adhere to the rules. Details at https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2578#section-3